# how to pass variable from DOM script to href link

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to pass a variable from java script to html link.

```
<li hidden><a id="url_call" href='/paytm/response/?response={{response}}' 
value="{{response}}">{{response}}</a></li>
<script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"></script>
<script>
  var options = {
    "key": "rzp_test_rpDFJlAD0LDl8Y",
    "subscription_id": "{{ sub_id }}",
    "name": "My Billing Label",
    "description": "Auth txn for sub_8seKGNhVEOwnjj",
    "handler": function (response){
      // alert(response.razorpay_payment_id);
      document.getElementById("url_call").click(response);
    }
  };
  var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);
  document.getElementById('rzp-button').onclick = function(e){
    rzp1.open();
  }
</script>
```

In the above code I want to variable response from

```
 "handler": function (response){
          // alert(response.razorpay_payment_id);
          document.getElementById("url_call").click(response);
        }
```

to

```
<li hidden><a id="url_call" href='/paytm/response/?response={{response}}' 
    value="{{response}}">{{response}}</a></li>
```

I think the way im doing is wrong. Could soemone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: The fact that you're using django for the backend is totally irrelevant - by the time the js code is executed it would work just the same if the html had been generated with PHP or Java or Ruby or was just plain static html... (tag removed)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value of `href` attribute as:

```
document.getElementById('url_call').setAttribute('href', '/paytm/response/?response='+response);
```

> Note `<a` tag does not have `value` attribute. [Click here to learn about valid attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp)

If you insist to change the value of `value` attribute, do this:

```
document.getElementById('url_call').setAttribute('value', response);
```

To change the text of `<a` tag use:

```
document.getElementById('url_call').innerText = response;
```

If you want all of the above changes, your final code will look like:

```
"handler": function (response){
   var el = document.getElementById('url_call');
   el.setAttribute('href', '/paytm/response/?response='+response);
   el.setAttribute('value', response);
   el.innerText = response;
}
```